# Kibana's Timelion: Field [timestamp_ms] of type [text] does not support custom time zones

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-spark, twitter, kibana

everyone!

I am trying to analyze a stream of tweets in real-time with Apache Spark, Elasticsearch and Kibana. As X-axis I want to have the value of the tweet's "timestamp_ms" property, as Y-axis I want to be the number of unique user ID's, giving me the reach of the tweets.

However, when I try to create an index, check the "index contains time-based events" checkbox and specify the property below, I run into a problem, which I will explain in a moment.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/twitter?pretty' -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "tweet": {
      "properties": {
        "timestamp_ms": {
          "type":   "date",
          "format": "yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

The problem is that when I start streaming the tweets into ES, I cannot display them with Timelion as this error occurs:

```
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [e1S9kLk][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field [timestamp_ms] of type [text] does not support custom time zones
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MappedFieldType.docValueFormat(MappedFieldType.java:453) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.support.ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder.config(ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder.java:374) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.support.ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder.resolveConfig(ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder.java:305) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.support.ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder.doBuild(ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder.java:299) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.support.ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder.doBuild(ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder.java:49) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AbstractAggregationBuilder.build(AbstractAggregationBuilder.java:126) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregatorFactories$Builder.build(AggregatorFactories.java:211) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregatorFactory.<init>(AggregatorFactory.java:187) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.filters.FiltersAggregatorFactory.<init>(FiltersAggregatorFactory.java:48) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.filters.FiltersAggregationBuilder.doBuild(FiltersAggregationBuilder.java:176) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AbstractAggregationBuilder.build(AbstractAggregationBuilder.java:126) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregatorFactories$Builder.build(AggregatorFactories.java:211) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:731) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:553) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:529) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:264) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService$6.messageReceived(SearchTransportService.java:300) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService$6.messageReceived(SearchTransportService.java:297) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:69) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$6.doRun(TransportService.java:577) [elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:527) [elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]
```

I've tried to set the following, but still doesn't work:

> timelion:es.timefield (Default: @timestamp) -> SET TO timestamp_ms
>
> timelion:es.default_index (Default: _all) -> SET TO twitter

Any ideas on how to fix this are appreciated, as I've researched quite a lot, but couldn't find anything that works for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the index and the index pattern, run a PUT request for the index once again, start writing to Elasticsearch, and create the index pattern another time. It should then show up on Kibana Discover.